# IPtables Config to Passthrough Internet 16.04

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, iptables, ip-forward

I am struggling to finish the config on my Ubuntu 16.04 fileserver to pass on the internet connection to my HTPC. See the network layout below:

[Internet] <--> [DHCP Router] <--> (eno1).[Fileserver].(eno2) <--> [HTPC]

The goal is such that the DHCP router will assign an unique address and to HTPC and the fileserver will pass through any necessary network traffic. Can someone take a look at the below and help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
 sudo sysctl -a | grep ip_forward
 net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

 sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
 sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eno1 -o eno2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
 sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eno2 -o eno1  -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching I figured out that I wanted to use a Bridge instead of IPTables. Otherwise, the connection would require another NAT/DHCP. The configuration of the Bridge is trivial, more detail can be found: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge